# Appendix header style has changed

Tags: header-footer, appendices

The header of my appendix is writing "appendix 6" instead of "appendix M"[image]

All other appendix headings are writing letters (A-L), so I don't understand why it has suddenly changed. [image]

Even the toc says the appendix is called "M" - so why does the heading say "appendix 6"? [image]

When I try to create a minimal working example to put in this question, the problem does not arise. So I am really confused. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is a MWE. The Main document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}

    \usepackage{amsmath}                            
    \usepackage{amssymb}                                  
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}                               
    \pagestyle{fancy} 

    \def\layout{2}  
    \ifnum\layout=2 
        \fancyhf{}      
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
        \fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{{\color{gray}\chaptername~ \thechapter}~ |~ \leftmark}}
        \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{ \rightmark}}
        \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
        \fancyfoot[LO]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{figure/auxiliary/DTUbioengineering.png}}
        \fancypagestyle{plain}{         
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}}
     \else          
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
        \fancyhf{}                  
        \fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{ \leftmark}}
        \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \fi


    \begin{document} 

    \tableofcontents

    \renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}
    \input{Appendices.tex}

    \end{document}
```

And the appendices:

```
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
  \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
}
\makeatother

\chapter{The first appendix}

\chapter{The second appendix}

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext
\blindtext

\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{appendices}
```

Comment: It's quite hard to say what is going on here with just a few pictures of the output. We would need to see the code that produced this. I realise that it is going to be quite time consuming to come up with an MWE in this case, but it is your best shot at getting a useful answer. You can copy your current document to a new folder and delete stuff until the issue disappears, then you add as much code as necessary to get the issue to resurface. That should make it possible to produce a minimal example.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) Without code, not really. are you messing with `\thechapter` anywhere?

Comment: Your name sounds Danish, where are you studying?

Comment: Okay. I'll try that.

Comment: No, I'm not messing with \thechapter except when I'm creating the header style.

Comment: Yep. I'm danish - From DTU

Comment: @moewe I followed your advice, and it seems the problem is due to references in the appendix. I guess it messes with the appendix, when the reference list is before the appendix. Is there anyway to fix that? Otherwise I might just make the references as footnotes.

Comment: Feel free to wrap everything up needed to build this into a ZIP file and send it to daleif@math.au.dk, then I'll have a look at it off site. BTW like on FB or twitter, if you use @<name> then they'll get an notification that you answered them

Comment: What references are we talking about here? Can you verify that it is indeed about the references? If you have isolated the source of the problem it should be much easier to create an MWE that reproduces the issue with very little code.

Comment: @moewe I use \cite{} in the appendix. When I remove it, the appendix name is correct. I think I will just use footnotes in sted of \cite, to avoid the issue. But thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks a lot @daleif, but I think I have found a solution.

Comment: Oh, please try to reproduce this in a minimal example. This really should not happen. If this is a bug it  can be helpful for other people if we manage to identify and report it.

Comment: @moewe OK, I did it. But now I'm even more confused... Apparently, removing the {\cite} only worked in the complete document, but not in the small example.

Comment: I get an error about an extra `\endgroup` introduced by `\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}`. Is that really necessary? Or do you also have a `\begingroup` somewhere, maybe in `\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}`?

Comment: @moewe Yea, sorry - I deleted to much. Have inserted the changes now.

Comment: I think I can reproduce the issue in a smaller context: `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{\thechapter}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{The first appendix}

\thechapter

\chapter{The second appendix}

\kant[1-8]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}` The problems seems to be the `appendices` environment. It seems to reset the counter on the last page...

Comment: I found a work-around. If I add `\clearpage` just before `\end{appendices}` things look much better. Can you check if it works in your real document, too?

Answer (score 2):

`appendix`'s `appendices` environment restores the previous chapter number at `\end{appendices}`. That means that the chapter number might be wrong for the header.

The issue can be reproduced in

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{\thechapter}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document} 

\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{The first appendix}
Lorem

\chapter{The second appendix}
\kant[1-8]
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

A work-around would be to add `\clearpage` or maybe even `\cleardoublepage` just before `\end{appendices}`

```
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{The first appendix}
Lorem

\chapter{The second appendix}
\kant[1-8]
\cleardoublepage
\end{appendices}
```

But maybe you can just get away with using `\appendix` instead of `\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}`.